# UNHANDLED_REJECTION: DiscordAPIError: Unknown interaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My code :

```
module.exports = {
    name: "plusbg",
    description: "Qui est le plus beau de ce serveur ?",
    run: (client, message, args) => {
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Le plus beau est Ratile')
        .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .addField (
            { name: 'Latence', value: `\`${client.ws.ping}ms\``, inline: true },
            { name: 'Uptime', value: `<t:${parseInt(client.readyTimestamp / 1000)}:R>`, inline: true},
        )
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter({ text: message.author.username, iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL() });

            message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]});
    },
    runSlash: (client, interaction) => {
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('DARK_VIVID_PINK')
        .setTitle('Le plus beau est Ratile')
        .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .addFields(
            { name: 'Latence', value: `\`${client.ws.ping}ms\``, inline: true },
            { name: 'Uptime', value: `<t:${parseInt(client.readyTimestamp / 1000)}:R>`, inline: true},
        )
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter({ text: interaction.user.username, iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL() });

        interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed]})
    },
};
```

(the message is in french)

I can use the commands on discord, it's working, but in the terminal there is an error called
Unknown interaction on the discord api.

```
-----
 Promise {
  <rejected> DiscordAPIError: Unknown interaction
      at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\ratil\Desktop\Bot - Skypiea\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\ratil\Desktop\Bot - Skypiea\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
      at async CommandInteraction.reply (C:\Users\ratil\Desktop\Bot - Skypiea\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:99:5) {
    method: 'post',
    path: '/interactions/992792318635683912/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246OTkyNzkyMzE4NjM1NjgzOTEyOkhUUnI5ZXF1bUw3WmxuR1RoN3gyU2N4eGFNYjYxWGgzb2JhWjhyOXVNTnlHSnQ4azhqRkxQaUF4QTVwZTFUZkxZNjVHdEhEOXh4WklTV2g0Yk9xM28yQURPUFBlS2Qwd050R3BSbHVGcFVFdDNXWWlHUW5xUXZZbFdpTzAyc3Ry/callback',
    code: 10062,
    httpStatus: 404,
    requestData: { json: [Object], files: [] }
  }
}
```

Can you help me please

The interactionCreate file (that's french too) :

```
module.exports = {
    name: "interactionCreate",
    once: false,
    async execute(client, interaction) {
        if (interaction.isCommand()) {
            const cmd = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
            if (!cmd) return interaction.reply(`Cette commande n\'existe pas`);
            cmd.runSlash(client, interaction);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What `interaction` do you pass to `runSlash: (client, interaction)`?

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't know what does it means 

Comment: `runSlash: (client, interaction)` we need to know what is `interaction` in that context, can you post code ?